# Qt C++ Video as background

Tags: c++, qt, animation, video, gif

Is there a chance to play video as background. To explain further, I would like to have video playing and on top of it to have widgets like pushbuttons etc. Is that possible?
Also I noticed Qt support gif animations, so is it good to convert video to gif and play it as background. I need it full screen. Regards.

Comment: No easy way, I think.

Comment: @Alen: do you already know the answer to your question?

Comment: No, I tried using QtMultimedia but it bring video in front of GUI controls and it consumes too much CPU so I quit doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Use phonon to play the video and then add widgets to the main window.

http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7/phonon-overview.html

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [QtMultimedia](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtmultimedia.html#details) as Phonon is getting replaced by it, cfr. [Phonon (KDE) on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonon_%28KDE%29):

> Even though support for Phonon in Qt will continue for the 4.x
>   series, Qt has already replaced Phonon with QtMultimedia and
>   QtMobility.

For Qt4.8 this means you additionally need to include Multimedia from [QtMobility](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qtmobility-1.2/).

As from Qt5, [Multimedia](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtmultimedia/multimediaoverview.html) is integrated into the framework.